# Journalist's daughter is on the run to U.S from a country at civil war

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie a decade back. I never got the name of movie, but I liked it lot. Can someone help me with the movie name?

1. It was not an English language film.
2. A journalist's daughter is on the run to the U.S (probably) from a country at civil war.
3. The civil war soldiers are given a tattoo for each kill under their name.
4. There is a small action sequence on top of a train (a train carrying goods, the people travel on top of these trains covering sheets above from the rain) where the lead actress hides under a green sheet as it was raining heavily and she is saved.
5. The lead guy is a rebel, but he finds the violence pointless and he helps this daughter to escape.
6. A critically acclaimed movie for depicting the war situation.
7. Entire movie is full of greenery, full of forests, even the train passes through some great locations, and it's raining all the time.
8. She manages to flee. In the last act there was room for only one person, so she gets on the boat to cross border. While this guy is waiting on shore for the next boat he gets shot by his apprentice, who is a very small kid.
9. Movie ends with the kid getting a tattoo on his face for the kill.

Comment: Nice details, anyways  do you know the release year or decade and when did you watched it?

Comment: Some of the details remind me of the movie 'Monsters', but  I cannot remember the tattoo bit. Sorry seems unlikely. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters_(2010_film)

Comment: @FranciscoV. Thanks for your response, but monsters is not the movie, the movie I watched was not English language film, and the movie was critically acclaimed .

Comment: @Chyavana sorry, I somehow ignored the "not an English" part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Cary Fukunaga's [Sin nombre](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1127715/combined) from 2009.

> Honduran teenager Sayra reunites with her father, an opportunity for her to potentially realize her dream of a life in the U.S. Moving to Mexico is the first step in a fateful journey of unexpected events.

It contains the elements you mentioned and ends the same way (the boat for one person, the girl getting on it and the guy being shot by a kid who gets a face tattoo for the kill). Here's the trailer: